# trying to understand javascript objects

Tags: javascript, object

I've written this piece of code to try help me understand how objects work in js a bit more.

```
function person(personName){
  var thiz = this;
  var nameOfMe = (typeof(personName) === 'undefined')? 'default':personName;
  var faveFood = 'stuff';

  thiz.speakName =function(){
    alert('I am '+ thiz.nameOfMe);
  }

  thiz.gotFoodAlert = function(){
    alert('Yummy! I haz ' + thiz.faveFood )
  }
}

var someGuy = new person('joe');
someGuy.faveFood = 'cheesecake';
someGuy.speakName();

var elseGuy = new person();
elseGuy.nameOfMe = 'bob';
elseGuy.speakName();
```

I'm trying to simulate a classical inheritance model to build a class then instantiate a person. Setting it separately in   elseGuy.speakName() alerts 'bob' ok.

What I don't understand is why doesnt the someGuy.speakName() alert 'joe' when I instantiate?

update: on further reflection and taking notes from people commented, I should just give up trying to simulate a classical inheritance model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `nameOfMe` is not a property of `this` in the first example. Try the following instead:

```
function person(personName) {
  var nameOfMe = (typeof personName === 'undefined')? 'default':personName;
  var faveFood = 'stuff';

  this.speakName = function () {
    alert('I am ' + nameOfMe);
  }

  this.gotFoodAlert = function () {
    alert('Yummy! I haz ' + faveFood )
  }
}
```

---

Even better:

```
function Person(personName) {
  this.nameOfMe = personName ? 'default' : personName;
  this.faveFood = 'stuff';
}

Person.prototype.speakName = function () {
    alert(this.nameOfMe);
};

Person.prototype.gotFoodAlert = function () {
    alert('Yummy! I haz ' + this.faveFood);
};
```

Comment: No, it works, just one small typo in the better version: this.nameOfMe = personName ? personName : 'default';

Comment: Your second version isn't really better. The first has something like private members whereas the second only has public ones.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `nameOfMe` as a property of `thiz`:

```
thiz.nameOfMe = (typeof(personName) === 'undefined')? 'default':personName;
```

Also, unless you absolutely have to, why don't you use the normal `this` instead of `thiz`?

Answer (score 1):

1. `thiz = this` aliasing is unnecessary here.  You only need it for "private" properties by additional closures.
2. `thiz.nameOfMe` is causing an additional closure here, needlessly.
3. The value of `thiz.nameOfMe` is not `"joe"` because the object referred to by `thiz` does not have a `nameOfMe` property yet.  The `nameOfMe` variable in constructor code is something else.
4. You are **not** using "the classical inheritance model". **There are no classes**. You are creating a `person` instance, that is, an object that has `person` as its constructor, and the object that `person.prototype` currently refers to next in its prototype chain. Nothing more, nothing less.
5. It is good code style to have constructor identifiers start with a capital letter: `Person`.

[RTFM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript).

Comment: PE, you are going to have fun here. :-)